# Lusztig's definition of quantum groups

Tags: lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, root-systems

In his book *Introduction to quantum groups*, Lusztig gives a definition (Def 3.1.1) of the rational form $U^{\mathbb{Q}(q)}_q$ that is rather different from the usual approach (see [1,Ch.9.1] for expample). As far as I understood, the translation goes as follows:

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra and $I$ a set of simple roots in $\mathfrak{h}^*$. Let $\Lambda_R:=\mathbb{Z}[I]$ denote the root lattice and $\Lambda_W$ the weight lattice of $\mathfrak{g}$.

For the **simply connected form**, take $Y=\Lambda_W$, $X=\Lambda^\vee_R$ (coroot lattice) and embed $I \hookrightarrow Y$, $\alpha_i \mapsto \alpha_i^\vee$ (note that $\Lambda^\vee_R \subseteq \Lambda_W$) and $I \hookrightarrow X$, $\alpha_i \mapsto \alpha_i$. This choice is isomorphic to what Lusztig defines as the simply connected root datum (2.2.2), and the corresponding relations $(a)-(d)$ in Lusztigs definition coincide with the simply connected form in [1].

Problems appear in the **adjoint** case: the choice $Y=\Lambda_R^\vee$, $X=\Lambda_W$, inclusions as above, is isomorphic to what Lusztig defines as the adjoint root datum, but this doesn't coincide with [1,Def 9.1.1] (most common definition), where only elements $K_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \Lambda_R$ are taken. So they restrict to $Y=\Lambda_R$, which in general gives a proper subalgebra of Lusztig's one.

But the choice $Y=\Lambda_R$, $X=\Lambda_W$ doesn't give a (rational form of a) quantum group in the Lusztig sense, since the pairing $\Lambda_R \times \Lambda_W \to \mathbb Z$ is not perfect and the first embedding doesn't work.

**QUESTION**: Why does Lusztig exclude the **standard example** of a Drinfeld-Jimbo algebra by restricting to perfect pairings on the root data? I mean in [2] he even defines the rational form in the "standard" way..

[1] Chari, Pressley - *A guide to quantum groups*

[2] Lusztig - *Quantum groups at roots of unity*

Comment: Crossposted on MSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985718/lusztigs-definition-of-quantum-groups

Comment: Is this just a pointer or a blame? If so, I didn't know that this is unwanted, and I can delete the other post!

Comment: It is generally discouraged to crosspost. It is very much frowned upon to crosspost without stating this, since it can lead to duplicate effort. I added the note to avoid the latter part.

Comment: Okay, sorry, the MSE post was an accident, I thought I'm on MO.. then I just duplicated it without further thinking.. I will delete the other post!